# How to enable top level await in angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

./node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js - Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

I have tried edit angular.json and tsconfig but no breakthrough.

Comment: What did you add to tsconfig.json?     "experiments": {
      "topLevelAwait": true
    }

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the compilerOptions, but it does not work.

Comment: It should be outside compilerOptions.

Comment: I have added it on the top level of the config object but still the same error is showing up.

Comment: I am using angular 16, and latest typescript

Comment: I have not managed to get it working for three days, Its so frustrating.

Comment: Do you have these in your compilerOptions 

    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "es2020",

Comment: I had es2022 but I have changed it to the options you have given.
"lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
"target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",

still the same error

Comment: I have the same problem, opened an issue on angular-cli repo and now it is opened for voting: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25178. For now i think the only way to solve this is using a previous version of Angular.

Comment: Thank you..
So what version have you chosen to go with. 15?

Answer (score 1):

This error also appeared to me, it seems that one of the library I was trying to use is for designed for Node and if wanting to use in the browser you have to import as mjs, but all of that is abstracted with the latest builder of Angular.

Simply put, I resolved it by upgrading to the latest Angular builder, I've updated my `angular.json`, with the following:

```
{
...
 "projects": {
   "my_project_name": {
     ...
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         // use latest builder for angular
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild"
       },
       ...
     }
    }
 }
}
```

I've gotten this answer from my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287375/4594452