# Error upon importing BSON library saying "The top-level-await experiment is not enabled"

Tags: angular, angular16

I get a top-level-await error upon when importing BSON:

```
./node_modules/bson/lib/bson.mjs - Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
```

[image: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)]

I'm importing the library inside my component like so:

```
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';
```

Been searching everywhere but can't find an answer.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors, post the error as code-formatted text.

Comment: Hey Mark, I've added the error as well but kept the screenshot as others might find the formatting helpful.

Comment: Did you try _"(set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)"_ as the error suggests?

Comment: I've resolved it by using the newest version of Angular builder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your angular builder to esbuild:

```json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
```

Still experimental in Angular, it'll be tagged as stable with the Angular 17 release.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/esbuild for more information too.